# being "ia" an integer array, printf("3[ia]:%d\n",3[ia]); WHY it works?

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int *ia[5]={0,1,2,3,4}; 

iap=ia; 
printf("ia[3]:%d\n",3[ia]); 
return 0;
```

}

Why is that line working in C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amazing world of C pointer arithmetic:

`ia[3]` is computed as `*(ia + 3)`, which is the same as `*(3 + ia)` or `3[ia]`.

You can also write `1[ia+2]`, or `3[ia-+!ia]`, or even `2[1+ia, ia+1]`...

None of these should appear in regular code unless you are trying to obfuscate and confuse the casual reader/maintainer/code reviewer.